# Can't access file

Tags: c#

I can't seem to get access to the file I'm working with in the program I'm writing. I'm not sure how exactly to work this since I want my program to open a file of your choice, which it does, then I want it to be able to take in info into an arrary, which it does, then from there, write that information from the array to the file you opened up. When I try some code to start working on it it tells me, "The process cannot access the file 'file' because it is being used by another process." Here is what I have so far. Please let me know. Thank you. The problematic areas is the Save_Click section of the code where I wrote "This is a test" Thanks.

```
     public partial class ListingSearch : Form
{
    string line;
    DialogResult result;
    string fileName;
    int i = 0;
    string[] first = new string[100];
    string[] last = new string [100];
    string[] phone = new string [100];
    string[] grade = new string [100];

    public ListingSearch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("Please be sure to open a file before beginning");
    }

    private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog filechooser = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            result = filechooser.ShowDialog();
            fileName = filechooser.FileName;
            System.IO.StreamReader file =
                new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] words = File.ReadAllText(fileName).Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n", ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                //firstName.Text = words[4];
                //lastName.Text = words[5];
                //telephone.Text = words[6];
                //GPA.Text = words[7];
            }
            Read.Enabled = true;
       }
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(fileName, "This is a test");
    }

    private void Read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(fileName);
        MessageBox.Show(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
    }

    private void info_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        first[i] = firstName.Text;
        firstName.Text = " ";
        last[i] = lastName.Text;
        lastName.Text = " ";
        phone[i] = telephone.Text;
        telephone.Text = " ";
        grade[i] = GPA.Text;
        GPA.Text = " ";
        i++;
    }

    private void displayinfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing to display!");
        else
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(first[j] + " " + last[j] + "\r" + phone[j] + "\r" + grade[j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You already got the answer: Your file is being used by another process. (Well... it could be your own process anyway :P)

Answer (score 2):

You get error here

```
File.ReadAllText(fileName)
```

because you open same file before it here

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
```

Comment: Actually, allow me to clear up some misunderstanding. That is actually not causing me a problem. What is giving me trouble is the fact that I press the save button on my program and the Save_Click command where I wrote File.AppendAllText(fileText, "This is a test"); is where I'm getting the error. I and trying to write more info to that file after I have it opened and then from there I want to close the file and be done with it but I'm not sure how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the file after you are finished reading it.  Also, not sure why you are opening the file at all, since you subsequently use `File.ReadAllText` which will handle opening and closing the file all on its own.

Seems like your `OpenFile_click` event should just look like this:

```
   using (OpenFileDialog filechooser = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        result = filechooser.ShowDialog();
        fileName = filechooser.FileName;

        string[] words = File.ReadAllText(fileName).Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n", ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        Read.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Well I'm still learning the software and I was asked by my professor to make a program that will display a window to allow me to chose any file of my choice to open and write to kinda like how you would with word. This is what I figured. I would open the file then use the readalltext to take it into the program.

Comment: @Skynet - I think you were on the right track.  The nice thing about using `File.ReadAllText` though is that you don't have to bother with opening and closing the file.  It handles all that internally so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I haven't tried the code yet but I am getting to it, what you are saying is that I'm just taking an extra step and putting a system lock on it so it can't be accessed? I can see how that works. System should lock it to prevent another program from altering it until its done with it. Didn't know my program would do that. Ultimately I like your method but it still needs to bring up the openfile dialog no matter what. Not sure if this will do it but I'll have to try it instead of having you all answer everything for me. lol

Comment: @Skynet - what I have should do what you want.  What you had before would actually open the file, iterate through each line in the file, then read the whole file again for each line.  So if you had 50 lines in the file, it would actually read the entire file 51 times.  If you were to step through it in the debugger, you should be able to see that happening.

Comment: I apologize for the newbie skills its just that, like I said, I'm still new to all this and I am undergoing a few different projects so my focus isn't entirely on there.

Comment: @Skynet - no problem, everyone has to start somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed your StreamReader.  C# will lock the file until you do.  Or you could use a StreamWriter after you closed your StreamReader